# Talend collation issue in mysql

Tags: sql-server, mysql, talend

I am using Talend to backup MS SQL to MySQL Server. Everything goes well, I have a connection, data flows from one db to the other... however I cannot correctly copy diacritic signs.

On MS SQL I have Polish_CI_AS and on MySQL I have Latin2 general_ci.

When I tried to copy data from MS SQL to an Excel file, everything is in place.
I concluded that problem lies in MySQL.

Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: you have to use the same character set everywhere, including the client->db connection. just because your table/field collation is 'X' doesn't mean the client->db will be using 'X' as well.

Comment: I can't find the same POLISH_CI_AS collation in MYSQL. Thus I used Latin2 general_ci which provides the same functionality (correct me if I am wrong). There must be a clever way of fixing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Talend MysqlOutput -> Component window -> Advanced settings. Add the following:

```
"useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=latin2"
```